# Convert date using react-moment

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I am using react-moment and trying to convert a date which is in this format 
14-Mar-2018 08:23:17 to 03/14/2018 08:23:17. How do I go about doing this? I am trying to render it in bootstrap-table-next.

```
const dateFormatter = (cell, row) => (
  <Moment parse="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss">
    {row}
  </Moment>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
const dateFormatter = (cell, row) => (
  <Moment format="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss">
    {row}
  </Moment>
);
```